# I am trying to create my first power apps application with 2 sql server connected tables

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to create my first power apps application with sql server connected tables I have most of it finished and doing what I want it to do. Just need to finish the last part. so the first screen shows all of the customers in a browser gallery. they click on the customer then that take them to a details page that shows customer information like customer ID  I then have a button for them to click that will take them to the Quote form and populate that form with the customerID as a global variable. On this form page I have the customer ID field pre populated with the global variable. I have begin date End Date, and filter. When they click search button I am taking them to another page like quotedetails passing in all of that information as  global variables

```
Navigate(
    QuoteResult,
    ScreenTransition.Cover,
    {
        BeginDate: BeginDate.SelectedDate,
        EndDate: EndDate.SelectedDate,
        filtertext: FilterDropDown.Selected.Value,
        CustIdText: CustText.Text
    })
```

on this last page I want to show only certain columns but filter it like a where statement

I have something like this

```
LookUp(
    '[dbo].[SOHeader]',
    CpnyID = "AOS" &&
        LUpd_DateTime >= BeginDate &&
        LUpd_DateTime <= EndDate &&
        SOTypeID = filtertext &&
        CustID = CustIdText)
```

then how would I tell it what particular columns I want from this table also

of course it is not working any help would be appreciated

the sql query to accomplish this would look something like this

```
SELECT   distinct SOHeader.OrdNbr, soheader.sotypeid, soheader.user6, SOheader.LUpd_DateTime, SOHeader.User3, soheader.crtd_user, SOHeader.S4Future01, SOHeader.SlsperID, SOHeader.TotMerch, SOHeader.CustOrdNbr 
FROM SOHeader 
WHERE (SOHeader.SOtypeID = 'SO'  AND SOHeader.Lupd_DateTime >= '5/16/2017'  AND SOHeader.lupd_DateTime <= '8/14/2017'  AND soheader.CpnyID = 'AOS'   and soheader.custid = 'LOCKT001')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out with using filter instead of lookup

Filter('[dbo].[SOHeader]',CpnyID = "AOS", CustID = CustIdText)

I decided to take out some columns while like the dates so I know I would get data